# In GAE, What is high replication datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am a newby in GAE and I want to get involved on almost everything, so this is the next step.

Comment: Vote to close as general reference: this is fully explained in the documentation.

Comment: Just read the datastore documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at: http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/01/announcing-high-replication-datastore.html

> The High Replication Datastore provides the highest level of
>   availability for your reads and writes, at the cost of increased
>   latency for writes and changes in consistency guarantees in the API.
>   The High Replication Datastore increases the number of data centers
>   that maintain replicas of your data by using the Paxos algorithm to
>   synchronize that data across datacenters in real time. One of the most
>   significant benefits is that all functionality of your application
>   will remain fully available during planned maintenance periods, as
>   well as during most unplanned infrastructure issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey the second link doesn't work.. Thanks anyways for sharing info.