# Google app engine datastore fast writing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

while starting to learn the google app engine datastore API I noticed the tutorial said:
"the rate at which you can write to the same entity group is limited to 1 write to the entity group per second". [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore)

I cant seem to understand how can you store a lot of user's information that needs to be written more than 1 time per second like: a simple app that let a user change a value on their profile or something like a comment or chat app that must write rapidly into the datastore

how can this be achieved? what have I missed here?

*if there's any samples or tutorials for a real application with the datastore it can be of great reference to me. (preferably in golang but anything will do)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of the bit you quoted is "entity group". Have you properly understood what that means?

A user updating their own profile is unlikely to happen more than once per second - that would require some very fast typing and clicking. As long as the profiles aren't in the same entity group then there's no reason, say, 10k users can't all update their profiles at the same time. For a chat, storing an entire conversation/room as a single entity would be tricky, but storing each message as its own entity wouldn't hit this limit.

Comment: ohh I think I did miss understand this, while storing each message as its own entity means I would have to query and not "get" the information, is this fast enough or is a good practice?

Comment: A chat that's being written to more than once a second isn't one that people are going to be reading in real-time, in its entirety, so immediacy or accuracy can probably be sacrificed. As with so much, "it depends".

Answer (score 0):

You have not missed anything, it's a way High Replication Datastore (HRD) works. It could be strange at first, but if you read about the benefits of HRD, you may find that it makes a sense.

If it's not suitable for you, you can use native [MySQL for GAE.](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/native-mysql-gae)

Also, there is a [closed question about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537354/in-gae-what-is-high-replication-datastore) this subject.

Comment: can you give an example of what the HRD is suitable for? I get the feeling that a chat app will not be using the HRD datastore as it will generate far more than 1 write per second, this limit seems VERY odd to me as I cant think of a large scale application that will meet these requirements

Comment: http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/01/announcing-high-replication-datastore.html

Comment: Comparison: Master/Detail vs.HRD is here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/usingmasterslave?csw=1